# How does the function $f(z)=\dfrac{\sin z}{z}$ have isolated singularity at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to ask how $f(z)=\dfrac{\sin z}{z}$ has a isolated  singularity at $z=0$? please someone tell.

Comment: Do you know the *definition* of an isolated singularity? This one is removable, BTW.

Comment: You divide by $z$. Division by $0$ is problematic. The singularity is however removable.

Comment: $\frac{\sin z}{z^2}$ has an isolated singularity.

Comment: Your function is holomorphic on $\Bbb{C}/\{0\}$.

Comment: Notice that $(\sin0)/0$ does not exist, but $\lim_{z\to0}(\sin z)/z$ exists and equals $1$.  So it's not just an isolated point where the function is undefined; it's also a point where there is a removable singularity.  (There is the problem of showing that when the singularity is removed, the resulting function is holomorphic.  If I were to write the details of that right now, I might have made it an answer rather than a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$ has an **isolated singularity** at $z=a$ if there is an $R>0$ such that $f$ is defined and analytic in $B(a;r)\setminus \{a\}$ but not in $B(a;R)$. [Conway, pg. 103]

What values of $z \in \mathbb{C}$ make your function non-analytic?